# HTML: iCal Link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar, icalendar

I'm just trying to create a link that when clicked will open up your default iCal application and add the calendar event within a hosted .ics file ...

I tried using the `webcal://` protocol, but that tries to "subscribe" to a calendar... not add an event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Serve an `.ics` file.

```
<a href="iCal-###.ics">Add to iCal</a>
```

Make one in iCal by control-clicking an event and choosing `Mail Event`, and use the file it creates.

Comment: @dcolumbus Have you tried checking to see if the web server you're using serves `.ics` files with the correct MIME type (i.e. `text/calendar` rather than `text/plain`)?

Comment: I'm using Safari. Is there a way of forcing the link to open correctly?